# java: regex for string

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to use regex to split string into field, but unfortunately it's not working 100% and is skipping some part which should be split. Here is part of program processing string:

```
void parser(String s) {
    String REG1 = "(',\\d)|(',')|(\\d,')|(\\d,\\d)";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(REG1);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s);
while (m1.find() ) {

            System.out.println(counter + ":  "+s.substring(end, m1.end()-1)+" "+end+   "  "+m1.end());
            end =m1.end();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

The string is:

```
s= 3101,'12HQ18U0109','11YX27X0041','XX21','SHV7-P Hig, Hig','','GW1','MON','E','A','ASEXPORT-1',1,101,0,'0','1500','V','','',0,'mb-master1'
```

and the problem is that it doesn't split `,1,` or `,0,`

Rules for parsing are: String is enclosed by  `,' ',` for example `,'ASEXPORT-1',`
`int` is enclosed only by `, ,`

expected output =

```
3101   |   12HQ18U0109  |  11YX27X0041  | XX21    |  SHV7-P Hig, Hig|  |GW1   |MON  |E  |  A|   ASEXPORT-1|  1  |101   |0   |  0  |1500  |   V|    |   |   0   |mb-master1
```

Altogether 21 elements.

Comment: Why don't you `String.split(',')` first and then look at the splits for if they are enclosed by "'" or not?

Comment: Could a string include a comma ? (E.g. 'str,ing')

Comment: I think you could just split the while string with "," and then the elements enclosed in single quotes would be string and the elements with no single quotes are int..

Comment: you should specify your expected output

Comment: if I split by "," it would also split single element into 2 for example  ,'SHV7-P Hig, Hig',

Comment: Then you should use another delimiter. Delimiters that can be in the data are bad. If you cannot do that, you can check the split if they start with ' but do not end with one. If the next ends in ' you can concat them, adding a ",", if it does not, it's an error.

Comment: Could a string contain an escaped `'` ? (E.g. `'SHV7 \'02'`)

Comment: Good catch @ExpertSystem. He'd have to take that into account, too.

Comment: there are no escaped, also no single quotes in main string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **split** it with this regex

```
,(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

It splits at `,` only if there are even number of `'` ahead

---

So for

```
3101,'12HQ18,U0109','11YX27X0041'
```

output would be

```
3101
'12HQ18,U0109'
'11YX27X0041'
```

---

**Note**

it wont work for nested strings like `'hello 'h,i'world'`..If there are any such cases you should use the following regex

```
(?<='),(?=')|(?<=\d),(?=\d|')|(?<=\d|'),(?=\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also (for some bizarre reason) need to know each matches start and end index in the original string (like you have it in your sample output), you can use the following pattern:

```
String regex = "('[^']*'|\\d+)";
```

which would match an unquoted integer or asingle-quoted string.
You can optionally remove the leading and trailing `'` using a "second-pass" on the matching substring:

```
match = match.replaceAll("\\A'|'\\Z", "");
```

which replaces a leading and trailing `'` with nothing.

The code could look like this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("('[^']*'|\\d+)");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);

int counter = 0, start = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1);
    int end = start + match.length();
    match = match.replaceAll("\\A'|'\\Z", "");   // <-- comment out for NOT replacing 
                                                 //     leading and trailing quotes 
    System.out.format("%d: %s [%d - %d]%n", ++counter, match, start, end);
    start = end + 1;   // <-- the "+1" is to account for the ',' separator
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/30W7uu)**.